# C++ types are abstraction from addresses? - C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, types, metaprogramming, c++-address

Unfortunately i have lost the link and the source for this article, but I do remember that it was about metaprogramming and templates in C++; when talking about the limitations around the template approach, this article was speaking about the fact that what is passed to a template it's not a generic type, but only types with a related address ( or addressable, I don't remember the exact words ) can be passed as arguments to a template.

Can someone clarify this relation between addresses, types and templates ?

A type can be identified with an address ?

---

***EDIT***

for example [at this link](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#stringliteral), in the last part of the linked FAQ, the template system is described like something that takes an address rather than a generic type.

Comment: Types are mostly only known at compile time (RTTI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information being the exception). An address does not have a defined type at runtime. (e.g. the return of `malloc` or `mmap`), since by casting a pointer to a different type you don't change the address it is containing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. The FAQ entry you cite is about passing **non-type** template parameters. Addresses to functions, integrals etc. are such. String literals are a tricky exception that doesn't work as you would expect and hence the FAQ entry.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't thinking of _linkage_ rather than "addressable"?

Comment: My guess is that maybe this has something to do with the fact that you can't really make a template that requires an uninstantiated template as a parameter. The C++ template expansion logic makes a strong distinction between instantiated and uninstantiated templates, and uninstantiated ones are sort of ghostly things you can only refer to in a very limited set of contexts. They certainly aren't types. Only instantiated templates are types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the original article you read, but the FAQ you linked to in the edit does *not* talk about a connection between types and addresses.

It talks about one specific kind of template parameters, the *non-type parameters*. There are three kinds of template parameters: *type*, *non-type* and *template*. So this is specifically about the second kind.

An example of a non-type parameter is `Id` in the definition below:

```
template <const char *Id>
struct C
{};
```

`Id` does not represent a type, but a non-type, i.e. an actual value. In this particular example, that value happens to be of a a pointer type, and it represents the address of a string.

The idea is that you can use this to instantiate the template using a string as distinguisher:

```
C<"foo"> c1;  // Instantiating the "foo" version of type C
C<"bar"> c2;  // Instantiating the "bar" version of type C
```

Unfortunately, it does not work like this – and that is what the FAQ article is about. It explains that for a non-type template parameter, you must use a constant expression, and in this particular case, you must use an identifier of an object with external linkage, not just a literal. So the only way you can do it is this:

```
template <const char *Id>
struct C
{

};

char id1[] = "foo";
char id2[] = "bar";

int main()
{
  C<id1> c1;
  C<id2> c2;
  /*...*/
  return 0;
}
```

That is what the FAQ article explains.

However, again, **this is a very special case**, because it applies to **non-type parameters of an address type only.** Note that the connection to *addresses* is given because the non-type parameter is explicitly specified as a parameter of pointer type `const char *`.

Most usual templates arguably use either a type-parameter or a non-type parameter of an integral, enum, or user-defined type. None of those has anything to do with memory addresses. There is no implicit connection between using templates and using memory addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a type identified with an address:

```
int foo;

template <int *IP>
class Bar {
};

Bar<&foo> baz;
```

But somehow, I don't think that's what the article meant.

Types themselves do not have addresses in C++. Individual definitions within a type may or may not have addresses of their own. And some things only have addresses within an instance of the type.

The trick I used up there can only be used on objects that exist for the entire lifetime of the program. And then the address of the object becomes part of the type's name.

And templates are not even types in C++. They are only a type when they've been instantiated with a particular set of parameters. And they don't have addresses either.

Comment: again, i'm sorry but i have lost this good link, it was more about design and generic limitations, it was talking about addresses like addresses not like pointers or references. More like what a template is supposed to accept as input and its structural limitations.

Comment: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#stringliteral confusion is rising but i think that that article was saying something similar to the last part of the FAQ at that link. But i can't remember exactly what this address thing was about ...

Comment: @Ken: I thought the 'name object with external linkage' thing too, but g++ is happy with a `static`.